# Minkowski diagrams when $\beta\to 1$

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

I was reading about Minkowski diagrams in Morin's *Introduction to Classical Mechanics*, pg.537, and was not able to understand a particular ratio.

He showed that a point $(x',ct')=(0,1)$ is at a distance $\gamma\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$ from the origin whose derivation made sense. So he next shows the relation between one $ct'$ unit and one $ct$ unit as:
$$\frac{one \ ct'\ unit}{one \ ct\ unit}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\beta^2}{1-\beta^2}}$$

I believe this is the scaling factor, so from this when $\beta\to1$, that is when it approaches the speed of light the scaling factor is infinite, what does this mean intuitively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a position vs time graph (a Spacetime diagram), the point $(x', ct')=(0,1)$ lies on a hyperbola centered at the origin and physically represents "one tick" of an inertial astronaut's watch, where the astronaut travels with velocity $v=\beta c$.

That point (event P) on the hyperbola can be written as
$$(\gamma v/c, \gamma)
=\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)
=(\sinh\theta,\cosh\theta),$$ where $\beta$
is the slope with respect to the vertical (time axis running upward) and
$\theta$ is the rapidity (the Minkowski angle [Minkowski arc-length on the hyperbola divided by the radius, twice the sector-area divided by the square-of-the-radius]).

**So, as $\beta \rightarrow 1$, the event P moves further up the hyperbola.**
These are the "first ticks" for a sequence of faster inertial observers.

The expression
$$\frac{one \ ct'\ unit \mbox{ drawn}}{one \ ct\ unit \mbox{ drawn}}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\beta^2}{1-\beta^2}}$$
is the **ratio of the Euclidean-lengths** of the segments (each representing  "one tick")
**if you use a Euclidean ruler on your diagram**,

since
one "$ct$" unit drawn has Euclidean-length $\sqrt{(0)^2+(1)^2}=1$
and
one "$ct'$" unit drawn has Euclidean-length $\displaystyle\sqrt{\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{\beta^2+1^2}{{1-\beta^2}}}$.
*That ratio describes what the diagram looks like.*

**So, as $\beta \rightarrow 1$, the drawn length of a worldline-segment from the origin to P gets very large (as P moves up the hyperbola).**

Here's the case for $\beta=3/5$:
[image: robphy-segments-06]

However, the physical ratio
$$\frac{one \ ct'\ unit \mbox{ on the $t'$-watch}}{one \ ct\ unit \mbox{ on the $t$-watch}}=1$$
is the **ratio of the Minkowski-lengths** of the segments (each representing  "one tick")
**if you use a Minkowski ruler [i.e. a watch] on your diagram**,

since
one "$ct$" unit on the $t$-watch has Minkowski-length $\sqrt{-(0)^2+(1)^2}=1$
and
one "$ct'$" unit on the $t'$-watch has Minkowski-length $\displaystyle\sqrt{-\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)^2}=1$.
*That ratio describes that their watches are using the same standard of elapsed time.*

**So, as $\beta \rightarrow 1$, the elapsed time on a watch along the worldline-segment from the origin to P remains constant at 1 (as P moves up the hyperbola).**

A Minkowski-ruler can be visualized as a **"causal diamond"** (the intersection of the future of the origin event and the past of the event P), since the **diamond-areas are equal** for all the causal diamonds with diagonal along $OP$, where $P$ is on the hyperbola.

Here's the case for $\beta=3/5$:
[image: robphy-causalDiamond-06]

Here's the case for $\beta=4/5$:
[image: robphy-causalDiamond-08]

---

Presumably, Morin will talk about "time-dilation",
which can be interpreted as the ratio of the vertical-components of these segments:

The expression
$$\frac{\mbox{vertical-component of } one \ ct'\ unit \mbox{ drawn or timed}}
{\mbox{vertical-component of }one \ ct\ unit \mbox{ drawn or timed}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-\beta^2}}=\gamma=\cosh\theta$$
is the **time-dilation factor.**
The stationary watch measures

 the elapsed time of "one tick of the moving watch"

 to be equal to "$\gamma$ ticks of the stationary watch". 
**So, as $\beta \rightarrow 1$, that ratio grows large (as P moves up the hyperbola).**